# uiOutput in 'between' argument of miniTabstripPanel causing incorrect page structure (shiny gadget with miniUI)

Tags: css, r, shiny

I was trying to add reactive elements to the bottom panel in dialog viewer. But it seems the css class "shiny-html-output" used by uiOutput is causing incorrect css styling of the page, pushing the tab buttons down below the window.
Here's a minimum example.

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

testfun <- function() {
ui <- miniPage(

    gadgetTitleBar("testgadget"),
    miniTabstripPanel(
        miniTabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table"),
                     miniContentPanel(
                         tags$p("Some data")
                     )
        ),
        miniTabPanel("Visualize", icon = icon("area-chart"),
                     miniContentPanel(
                         tags$p("Some figure")
                     )
        ),

        between = list(
            uiOutput("sometext")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$sometext <- renderUI({
        return("some text")
    })

    observeEvent(input$done, {
        stopApp()
    })

}
runGadget(ui, server, viewer = dialogViewer("test"))
}
```

Is there any workaround to this? Thanks!